# how to import "process" package?

Tags: python, import, process

I'm using "eye tracking" Git code, and my pyChram can't import "process" package.

```
import process
```

I tried to import process through pip (by cmd). it failed and output

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement process (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for process
```

Also, I tried to look into https://github.com/stepacool/Eye-Tracker but no information about it.

Comment: `process.py` is a module in the repository that you link, `import process` should just import that module. You are probably trying to run `main.py` from a different path, run it from the same path and it should work.

Comment: In context of OP he probably means `process.py` in the root directory of the Eye-Tracker package.

Comment: @jdehesa that's it! but could you advise me how to make the main run from that same path? how to choose which path to run my main?

Comment: @Omri How are you running the program? As the repo suggest, you should open a prompt, navigate to the directory and run `python main.py`. If you are using a script or a shortcut or something like that to run it then you would need to configure that.